# Android CloudRail Branded site fails - "Unexpected token )" (community.js line 18)

Tags: javascript, android, syntax-error, dropbox, cloudrail

Since yesterday i can't login to dropbox account using Android CloudRail Integration. My code is as simple as this:

```
CloudRail.setAppKey([License Key]);

final CloudStorage cs = new Dropbox(this.getApplicationContext(), "[clientIdentifier]", "[clientSecret]");
new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        cs.createFolder("/TestFolder"); // <---
        InputStream stream = null;
        try {
            AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
            stream = assetManager.open("UserData.csv");
            long size = assetManager.openFd("UserData.csv").getLength();
            cs.upload("/TestFolder/Data.csv", stream, size, false); // <---
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle error
        } finally {
            // TODO: close stream
        }
    }
}.start();
```

All i'm getting is "Connecting to Dropbox" page and

I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(18)] "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )", source: https://integrations.cloudrail.com/community.js (18)

in Android Studio console.

Line 18 is:

```
setTimeout(() => { //line 18
    window.location.href = redirectUrl;
}, 3000);
```

I'm using a few real devices (Android 5, 6, 7) and some emulated ones. One or two devices are still working (quite slow).

Help me please. Is this some temporary issue of Cloudrail? I couldn't find any info. I haven't changed anything recently.

Answer (score 0):

We updated the community authentication page which probably introduced the issue. I just realized that the lambda notation is not supported on some mobile device so I reverted to the old way of doing it. Could you please validate that it works now.

Comment: Much better now. Tested on Androids 4.1, 5.1 and 7.0. Thank you.